# React sorting of the array relative to type

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have a json file with data. from this file I want to ask questions and the type of question. the structure is to look like this: there is a category name + picture, and then a list of questions.
This is my component that renders the list of questions.

```
import React from 'react';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';
import QuestionsListItem from './QuestionListItem';

const images = require.context('../../img', true);
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true);

const QuestionsList = ({ questions }) => {
  const questionListItem = questions && questions.questions ?
    sortBy(questions.questions, ['type']).map((question) => (
      <>
        {
          const sortType = (question) => {
            if(question.type==='science') {
              <img src={imagePath('./star.png')} alt="star" />
              <p>{question.type}</p>
            }
          }
        }
        <QuestionsListItem
          key={question.id}
          type={question.type}
          question={question}
        />
      </>
    )) : null;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        { sortType }
        { questionListItem }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

At the beginning, I want to sort the array with a type, then I want to map it, then I want to render the type, if `type ===" since "` show the appropriate text and picture. At this element I get the error `Parsing error: Unexpected token` and points to`const sortType = (question) => {...`. I do not know how to do it in React to get the effect I want. Where to insert the code responsible for type and category image rendering?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: add return after your if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the function `sortType` in the JSX part of your file. This isn't allowed.

Moreover, in your `sortType` function, you must return JSX, and when you call your function, you must give it the `question` as argument.

Here would be the correct code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';
import QuestionsListItem from './QuestionListItem';

const images = require.context('../../img', true);
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true);

const QuestionsList = ({ questions }) => {

  const sortType = (question) => {
    if(question.type==='science') {
      return (<>
        <img src={imagePath('./star.png')} alt="star" />
        <p>{question.type}</p>
      </>)
    }
  }

  const questionListItem = questions && questions.questions ?
    sortBy(questions.questions, ['type']).map((question) => (
      <QuestionsListItem
        key={question.id}
        type={question.type}
        question={question}
      />
    )) : null;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        { sortType(question) }
        { questionListItem }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the star image ? Once before the list of question or before every question with the type "science" ?

Comment: Once before the list of question. Then I have different categories of questions, e.g. fashion. I want to show a picture related to fashion and a list of questions

Comment: I see. Then instead of `sortBy`, you should use `groupBy` to divide your questions by types. Then, map over the categories, print the image, then map over the question of this category, and print the question